# Regular Expression in Blackberry?

Tags: regex, blackberry-jde

How to validate email by using Regular Exprssion in Blackberry. There is no Pattern class in Blackberry API. Is there any other way to validate.
                              Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Regex in the current Blackberry API.
Try this: http://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://rndm-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/11/blackberry-jde-validate-email-address.html) is a good example using Regexp-me to validate the email address in Blackberry JDE.