# How to use quantifier regex pattern on blackberry ({m,n})

Tags: java, regex, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Hi im trying to write a validation class using : [regexp-me](https://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/) lib because of the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212172/regular-expression-in-blackberry).

**What did i do**

```
String id = "123456789";

String pattern = "\\d{7,8}";

public boolean validate(String id,String pattern){


    RE regular_expresion = new RE("\\d{7,8}");

    return regular_expresion.match(id);
}
```

This code should have returned false with that "id" since the pattern just should accept 7 to 8 digits. However if i use id = "1234567" it return true , the code is accepting 7 or more digits.

**The {m,n} is working as a {n,}.**

Has someone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `\\d{7,8}` means:

- find anywhere within the string
- a string consisting only of digits
- with at least 7, but not more than 8 characters.

This is true for `1234567` as this is a string of 7 digits as well as for `123456789` because also this string contains a string with 7 or 8 digits.

Change the expression to `^\\d{7,8}$` to get a positive result only when the entire string from beginning to end consists of only digits and the string length is either 7 or 8.

Comment: Wow so the method return true even if it has a substring with that pattern. My bad thank you Mofi.